# Book identification-Takes place in England with a Dragon and a Chinese Girl

Tags: story-identification, dragons

I read this probably back in 2004-2005.

Anyways the book/novel is being Narrated by this British youth to a Monk whose been charged with writing his every word.  The novel then follows his pursuit of a Dragon along with a Chinese girl (her feet are bound and everything).  At one point the girl gets her feet unbound and later when they find a wealthy Chinese merchant who'd be keen on marrying her if she got her feet bound once more.  She refuses.

Sorry that's not much to go on.

Comment: @Wikis, the Dragon perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

The Hunting of the Last Dragon by Sherryl Jordan. 2002.

In this story within a story, Jude, a young, illiterate peasant at a monastery in 1356 England, unsparingly dictates to Brother Benedict the events that occurred during a journey taken with a young Chinese noblewoman, Jing-wei. Having rescued Jing-wei from a band of traveling performers who were showing her as a heathen freak, Jude and the woman elude their pursuers, only to be driven off by superstitious villagers. It is Lan, a wise old Chinese woman (reputed to be a witch) who straightens Jing-wei's bound feet and reveals Jude's destiny: he must kill the last dragon, which has been terrorizing the people of St. Alfric's Cove . . .

Comment: Yes, the heroine simply unbound her feet then was able to set off on a journey after they healed... definitely a fantasy! (But a good story other than that!)